# EasyMock incompatible return value type for return type Collection

Tags: easymock

I am getting the following exception for a method where the return type of the method is collection...

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: incompatible return value type
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.andReturn(MocksControl.java:218)

expect(training.getTrainingMaterials()).andReturn(new HashSet());
```

where the `training.getTrainingMaterials()` --> return type is Collection..

Can you please help me what needs to be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add complete signature of `getTrainingMaterials()`!

Comment: even i have put as HashSet<TrainingMaterial>() in the andReturn but it gives me the same error.

Comment: public Collection getTrainingMaterials()
 {
   return this.trainingMaterials; }

Comment: declared as Set trainingMaterials = null; on the top..later assigned it to a HashSet

Answer (score 0):

I see where my problem is.

If you are using EasyMock.createMockBuilder(XXX.class)

Make sure you remember to addMockedMethod("methodName").createMock();